# VLA's memory available under gcc

Tags: c, variable-length-array

As malloc returns NULL, is there any way to detect that there is insufficient memory on the stack using VLA's?

Comment: a stack fault comes to mind. If you think the number may be unreasonable, don't gamble; use `malloc()`

Comment: "If you have to ask, you can't afford it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in C to guarantee the success of declaring a VLA or checking for failure regarding memory usage. This is the same for any declaration of an automatic object, VLA or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what's the behaviour when there is not enough space for store automatic objects? the program doesn't start because required space is know at runtime? it start but crashes? (Excuse my poor english)

Comment: @DavidRF usually it starts to crash (segmentation fault for example) soon after entering into the function, after the declaration of the object. But it may do anything as we are in the realm of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can hope for a crash, but the worst case scenario is that things will seem to work and you'll end up writing to some other memory. At least gcc by default doesn't generate code that makes an attempt to verify that the memory is available (there's an option for it though), so a large enough VLA can end up anywhere. On MacOS you only need a 0.5MB VLA in a threaded process to accidentally end up writing to the stack of some other thread. 10MB on Linux.

If you can't guarantee that a VLA is small (less than a page or two) don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc()` checks the heap, `VLAs` work on increasing the stack size. if `malloc()` returns `NULL` chances are your stack has been filled too.

As WhozCraig points out, do not gamble with VLAs. If the array size is big - use `malloc()`