# printing string from the array

Tags: arrays, c, string, loops

***as you can see this while I run this it works perfectly till "The array is " but cant show the string that I enter***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int size;
    char arr[size];
    printf("input size of array ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("\ninput elements of array  ");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", &arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\nThe array  is ");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Couple of issues: `char arr[size];` is a 1d array that can hold a single c-string. Also, `size` is uninitialized at that point so even when you change `size` later, the array is already created.

Comment: To fix: _first_ get `size` from the user, then declare: `char arr[size][100];`. Also, you can change to `scanf("%s", arr[i]);`...*You can change `100` to the max string length you expect.

Comment: Sidenote: VLAs can be tricky to use. If the user enters a very large value for `size` you can overwrite the stack. Dynamic memory allocation (`malloc`) might be better here. [Is it required that a C Variable Length Array is allocated from the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33020514)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things wrong with this code.

```
int size;
char arr[size];
```

You are declaring a `char` array `arr` with `size` elements, but size is not yet initialized yet and may be any value. Also note that "deciding the size of an array at runtime" is only valid in modern C (C99 onwards).
You should first read `size` and only after the `scanf` declare `arr`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    scanf("%s", &arr[i]);
}
```

You read a string (`%s`) with `scanf` and try to store it in a `char` (`&arr[i]` points to the ith char in `arr`). Every C string is atleast 1 character long (the terminating `\0` character), you are trying to store multiple characters in a single `char`.
Instead use

```
scanf("%s", arr);
```

Note that `scanf` is not safe. Even if you enter more than `size` characters, it will still try to store them in `arr`. That leads to undefined behaviour, because `arr` is too small. Instead you can use `fgets`, that lets you set the number of characters to read.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
}
```

Here you are trying to print a String (`%s`), but you are passing a `char` (`arr[i]` is the ith char in `arr`).
Instead use

```
printf("%s\n", arr);
```